# Draw google maps radius and get countries

Tags: google-maps, draw, countries

I like find all countries within a set radius (variable) from a defined address (variable) with Google maps. Drawing a radius on a map is easy, but getting the mapped countries looks difficult. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK this can't be done with GoogleMaps.

Suggestion: Download all the countries' bounds from [GADM](http://www.gadm.org/) and write your own lookup.

Comment: The url does not work. Is there any approaches based on OpenRefine?

Answer (score 0):

Not a 100% watertight solution but an approach that I know works if your radius is not too large:

- get the lat/lng of the address
- calculate the lat/lng of several points on the radius boundary surrounding the address (easiest is to take e.g. the 4 points at 0, 90, 180 and 270 degrees; so calculate those lat/lng's by taking the radius distance north, east, south and west of your given address)
- reverse geocode all 5 (or more) those lat/lng's and accumulate all countries of the places that you get back (this can be done in batch operation with certain geocode api's but I believe not with Google's)

Of course at addresses where there is complex shaped country borders this won't be bullet proof. Then you will need more points on the radius boundary; and if your radius is very large then even points inside it as well; but the more you take the more expensive the reverse geocode will get of course.